# recover lost C# pages

Tags: c#, web-services, dll

I had a problem I lost all my source(CS) of web site pages but I had only published pages on server ,so please if there is any way to recover theses published pages to orignal pages with code,bin folder

Comment: I made you a web page, but I eated it :)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. Are you talking about a CMS?

Comment: Depends on how the publish was made, was it a web-site or a web-application, was the code obfuscated?

Answer (score 4):

You need to decompile the C#. It is an advanced user scenario, but it can be done... sort of.

[How do I decompile a .NET EXE into readable C# source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-source-code)

Answer (score 2):

try to use reflector. it help you to restore all your code

Answer (score 1):

Use your latest backup copy, or roll back to the previous version of SVN you are working on.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/ is a good piece of software for recovering source from a compiled program.

Answer (score 0):

If your project was a website, you should be able to ftp each file from the server 1 for 1. If your file was a web application project, you're hosed. The code files are compiled into a binary, and if you lost the source code it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/ Can decompile .NET assemblies into source code - however it won't be the code you wrote as alot of it will have been changed by the compiler (IE your comments will have gone bye bye)

You can then rebuild your Project in your IDE of choice and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If the assemblies haven't been obfuscated, you can use [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to recover your code from the assemblies.