# How to create the build of PHP application

Tags: php

I have developed a web application in php. And i need to host it in the server. But before that i have convert the source code into build. How can i achieve this..

Comment: PHP apps run just fine as-is, they don't need to be compiled. Can you clarify what you mean by "convert into build"?

Comment: I have never heard about PHP source code build.

Comment: I dunno, tools like [phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/) that adopt practices from other languages can sure make it *look* like you're "build"ing something.  Maybe we can hold the close party for a bit while we let the asker explain?

Comment: I am new to Php.. I know ASP.Net, in Asp.net we were Using "BUILD" option. That means, the IDE(Framework) will compile the code and it wil ignore the .aspx.cs file and it will show only .aspx file in that build folder... Is there any options like that in php...

Comment: AFAIK php can be compiled into bytecode just for deploy desktop application... maybe this can explain it better: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bcompiler.php or, if you need to "protect" your sources... http://www.ioncube.com/ but it's a professional solution.

Comment: @Gnanendra: PHP is a scripting language, it doesn't need to be built like ASP.

Answer (score 2):

> in Asp.net we were Using "BUILD" option. That means, the IDE(Framework) will compile the code and it wil ignore the .aspx.cs file and it will show only .aspx file in that build folder... Is there any options like that in php

No, nothing like that is necessary for PHP. You just upload your folder full of .php files to the server and that's it.

Comment: Is it...??? Then that can be hack by the hackers right..? In asp.Net no one can able to see the server side scripts...... So its difficult to hack also..

Comment: @Gnanendra, .Net bytecode is [trivial to decompile back into workable source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-source-code).  Visibility of source code has zero to do with being "hacked."  If you are truly concerned about others seeing your code or interfering with your data in any way, then you need to be on dedicated hosting, not shared hosting.

Comment: @Gnanendra If somebody has access to your server to such an extend that they can access your source code, compiled or not, you're already screwed. The format of the executable files is irrelevant.