# Can i decompile asp.net mvc 4 dll files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, reflector

I am working on de compiling my old mvc4 source code which has only dll files in it, i would like to know if it is possible i have already used reflector and got some of the source files but it looks like the source is all messed up.

any thoughts.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I decompile a .NET EXE into readable C# source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-sharp-source-code)

Comment: any thoughts... yeah, don't lose your source code!

Comment: You won't get exact source as well, the compiler expands on a lot of code (lock -> Monitor.Enter/Exit) etc.

Comment: i think you missed the concept bilyachat, i said its mvc dll not .net exe. that too it has EF on top :( musefan i didnt lost it is done by some other mate.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use [ILspy](http://ilspy.net/) , the open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler.

Answer (score 0):

try to decompile dll using Decompiler by Telerik http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx