# Lost my code visual studio but still got the publish folder, is it possible to get my code back?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I lost my code but I published the code a few days ago in visual studio. Is it possible to reverse the .manifest files and .deploy files back to c# code?

Edit: its a console application
This is all i have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Qd5.jpg

Comment: What did you publish?

Comment: I published my code in visual studio. In visual studio 2010 > build > publish "myprojname". And in my publish folder there is a .exe a clickonce app and a folder which contains .manifest and .deploy files

Comment: A website? A windows desktop app? A web api service? etcetc

Comment: It is a console application

Comment: When you say lost it you mean?

Comment: I just changed the code to something whole different, and saved it... But I still have the publish map of a few days ago

Comment: Undo undo undo.... you got good lesson. Now it is time to learn about revision control systems.

Comment: That is not possible anymore, that back far. Probably because I closed Visual Studio

Comment: Try to use Reflector to decompile files you got. Maybe in some magical conditions you can find previous version of changed file by using right clicking onn file->Properties->Previous Version (in file explorer)

Comment: Thanks @Reniuz this fixed my problem, i can see my code now :D im so happy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-sharp-source-code)

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) and its add-in [FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/Home/ReflectorFileDisassembler).

Reflector will allow to see the source code. FileDisassembler will allow you to convert it into a VS solution.

Comment: I just drag the .exe to the reflector right? it tells me : `File is not a portable executable. DOS header does not contain 'MZ' signature.
`

Comment: load only the executables/dlls and not the manifest files... which file gives you the error? if you rename the ...*.deploy file to .* (without deploy) can you execute your program?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using any Source-Control-System your code is lost.

You can try to get back your code by decompiling your published version. Therfor you can use something like ILSpy.

Comment: Damn it, this will be a wise lesson tho. thanks for the help tho :) gonna try ILSpy