# How can I make the published code of EXE as readable in C# asp.net. Is there a way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exe

I lost the original source code of my `.exe`. Now I want to edit some more changes. Is there is any way to make the published code of `.exe` as readable in C# asp.net?

Comment: Hey thanks i got it

Answer (score -1):

[Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) and its add in [FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/Home/ReflectorFileDisassembler)

Reflector will show the source code and FileDisassembler will convert it into Visual Studio Solution.

Please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-sharp-source-code).

And for more knowledge you can check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/883888/Converting-exe-into-a-readable-source-code) as well.