# Change SMTP address in DLL or intercept the email sent to old SMTP address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, dll, smtp

I have a live MVC application running on production server. Whenever a user registers on the site, the MVC application sends an email to the registered user.

Now, the SMTP server has been changed to a new IP address. And the old SMTP IP address is hard coded in one of the DLLs used by the application. The application it is not reading SMTP address from web.config file.

I do not have the source code to recompile the code with new SMTP address.
The problem is that the registered user never gets the confirmation email.

Is there anyway I can change the IP address used in the DLL?

Or is there anyway I can intercept the email sent to the old SMTP address and then resend the same email to new SMTP server.

Please suggest any possible solutions.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but you might want to try to decompile that dll http://stackoverflow.com/q/179741/578411 and then re-compile it with your changes. Keep in mind though that this is not guaranteed to work and you'll have to test all methods used in the dll to make sure it still works. And if the dll is signed this route will  not work.

Comment: Tried that already but as you said it's not easy. Cannot compile back to working code.

Comment: Is that ip-address a const? So is it used as `var smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");` or is it an instance or static variable? You can find that if you de-compiled it already. Please add to your question what the code looks like.

Comment: Host the SMTP service on the old IP Address? Or is it configured to use a DNS entry?