# How to open / edit an exe in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i deleted my old project from repos but i want to edit it again but i don't know how to do.

I want to edit form and my codes please help.

My project:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQCyz.png)

Comment: You don´t open an **assembly**, but a **project** in Visual Studio. The project is **compiled into** an assembly. Btw.: your image is completely useless.

Comment: You can't. The source files are gone. However, you can use DotPeek to decompile an exe. It might be janky though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try what is suggested here : [How do I decompile a .NET EXE into readable C# source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/179744/8233385)

The purpose is to deassemble the code to be able to edit it again. But you will have some work to do cause the code will probably be quite different from the one you wrote.

Comment: There no have thing about how to make.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have you .soln file anywhere with the source code? You can use visual studio to open that. 
Did you delete the repo or did you just delete all your code and push that change up to your repo? if its the latter, i would look into how to revert your codebase to a previous revision

Otherwise, the only thing i can think of doing is running your exe and dlls through a de-compiler but the code will not be the same as when you wrote it.

Comment: I just deleted project from repos and i decompiled my project so i have codes.