# Zebra SDK adds extra ^XA at the beginning of the file when storing file in the printer

Tags: c#, .net, zebra-printers, zebra-scanners

I need to store a couple of labels in ZPL format in a Zebra printer. I'm using Zebra SDK with C#

My code:

```
foreach (var label in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Labels\"))
{
    PrinterUtil.StoreFile(CONNECTION_STRING, label, item.Replace(@"C:\Labels\", "R:"));                                
}
```

The file uploads, but does not print because at the first line the printer add an extra ^XA or in some cases ÿþ^XA.
The original file already starts with ^XA. So I have to remove the line that the printers adds to been able to print the label.

Is there some configuration code I'm missing? Any ideas?

Comment: What does the documentation on `PrinterUtil.StoreFile` say? The `ÿþ` is the [UTF-16 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16).

Comment: The docs say nothings. The URL is https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/pc_net/content/html/d79c6636-32e0-64db-6300-04c8f5894f0c.htm

Comment: I would then [decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7664693/11683) and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

^XA denotes the start of label and ^XZ denotes the end of label. If you are trying to print multiple labels together, then ZPL file would comprise multiple ^XA...^XZ blocks. You can use http://labelary.com/viewer.html to preview your labels.