# How to decompile very old version VB EXE to Source Code

Tags: vb.net, exe, decompiler

**Our team has been using a *.exe file developed during window XP or 6 OS timeframe.. I am also not sure which version of Visual Basic (may be VB6), as this code is been written in 2004.

Currently, team is struggling to access it on a virtual XP machine. Unfortunately, the source code was lost. Would it be possible to open the source using any of the VB.Net frame work applications from the *.exe file only

Now I am trying to ***decompile .exe and generate source code***.

**Tried Solution:**

1. Installed 32 bit dotpeek and tried but no success.
2. Also tried through command line "ildsam" but still no success
   *[How do I decompile a .NET EXE into readable C# source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-sharp-source-code)*

Above solution tried on below machine

1. Dell laptop (Precision 7560) with Windows 10
2. Visual Studio 2022.

**Is anyone tried/faced issue like this**.

**Is there any way to find out which version of VB from .exe**

On which version of

Please let me know your suggestion

Comment: If the application is that old, you're most likely wasting your time - it's past end-of-life.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3362/how-to-know-in-which-language-technology-program-exe-is-written

Comment: If ildasm doesn't work, then it may be native-compiled VBA-heritage VB code.  The "native-compiled" part means that trying to get source code from it is no different than trying to get source code from a C or C++ program, though the VB part means that there will be certain conventions and patterns in what comes out.  The results are not likely to be very satisfactory, if you want to update the program you're probably better off writing a detailed spec for what the existing program does and rewriting from scratch.