# Debug closed C# dll file without source code

Tags: c#, debugging, pdb

I have a C# program that uses a DLL that was written in C# FW 4.0. I don't have the source code or the pdb for the dll. It throws an error but doesn't say exactly what happened. How can I debug it and see the exact line that causes the error?
I tried attaching VS 2022 debugger but f11 won't step into the closed DLL code.

Comment: _"written in C# FW 4.0"_ You mean .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Maybe you can disassemble it and try to recompile it and see what happens? This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179741/how-do-i-decompile-a-net-exe-into-readable-c-sharp-source-code

Comment: What's the purpose of that analysis? If you don't have, nor _own_ the code, all you need to know is that it has a bug and how to reproduce it. Package that knowledge and file a bug report with the author. On _your_ side, you should focus on a workaround until the bug is fixed - or if that's unfeasable, look for a replacement. If you managed to debug it somehow and could pinpoint the exact line - you still could'nt fix the lib, could you?

Comment: @Fildor I hope that by knowing what causes the error, I can send different parameters that will cause it to work properly

Comment: You can turn on "break when thrown" for "common language runtime exceptions" in the exception settings window. That should give you a call stack where the exception occurred. I think VS2022 can also decompile the code for you, but things like inspecting variables might not work.

Comment: Ah, so basically you _are_ working towards a work-around. In that case, I'd try what Jonas suggested but don't expect too much.

Comment: "It throws an error but doesn't say exactly what happened" checked also the inner exceptions here? There might be more information "hidden".